# Python pickle load time not uniform?

Tags: python, performance, time, pickle, uniform

Can someone explain what is happening here?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pickle
from time import perf_counter_ns as timer

def timeit (run) :
    def timeit_ (f) :
        def inner (*args, **kwargs) :
            t1 = timer ()
            for r in range (0, run) : result = f (*args, **kwargs)
            tt = timer () - t1
            print (f'{f.__name__} {tt / 1000000 / run:10.2f} ms')
            return result
        return inner
    return timeit_

@timeit (10)
def pickle_R_0 () :
    with open ("sklearn_model_0.pickle", "rb") as f :
        ats0 = pickle.load (f)
    return ats0

@timeit (10)
def pickle_R_1 () :
    with open ("sklearn_model_1.pickle", "rb") as f :
        ats1 = pickle.load (f)
    return ats1

@timeit (10)
def pickle_R_2 () :
    with open ("sklearn_model_2.pickle", "rb") as f :
        ats2 = pickle.load (f)
    return ats2

pickle_R_0 ()
pickle_R_1 ()
pickle_R_2 ()
```

returns

```
pickle_R_0     263.07 ms
pickle_R_1       1.43 ms
pickle_R_2       1.48 ms
```

Files loaded are the same file with different names. Why the first one takes so long while consecutive loads are much faster, while being different functions and filenames?

What got me thinking is in my project I import this sklearn model and using profiler I noticed pickle load is now taking up to 6s! While here same file loads much faster on the same machine. But they are still not uniform times, so what gives?

Comment: Almost certainly the first load is importing classes that are being represented by the object you are loading.  It probably has to load in a lot of sklearn.  The second loads find that these classes are already imported.

Comment: Follow Up.  Looks at `sys.module.keys()` after the first load and see if it has gotten appreciable longer.

Comment: `def timeit (run) :` *just use the built-in module `timeit`*

Comment: @FrankYellin you are right, i was overlooking this feature.